# How to add different action in customize listview

Tags: android, android-listview

How to add different action in custom listview , here i've done by switch case but if i do this i have to create different activity for this, which is kill my time , is there any solution ?
can i add different image , text, button, calling button for different row in OnItemClickListener() in a 
single activity.

Comment: this is not very clear question..You have a listview with just text and you want to add image and buttons or you want to do one clickListener for every row in listview?? What have you done so far? can you post your code?

Comment: Thanx  @KostasMatrix can i get your mail address. i tried but could not add my code.

Comment: yes its simbaineitwra@gmail.com

Comment: Thanx for your respons. Please check your mail